# Using mouse data to control cursor - libusb

Tags: usb, libusb

I have used libusb to find a usb mouse in my system, detach the associated kernel driver associated with it and read the data from its endpoint which gives me an array of information that is sent from the device to the host.

Since I detached the kernel driver, the mouse pointer does not move when moving the mouse physically (which is alright). However I now want to use the obtained data (as above) to move the mouse pointer without actually moving the mouse. So I need to know where and how to write this data to achieve this objective.

Please guide me on how I can do this.